# Fread reads over EOF

Tags: fread

I'm on Linux.

i have a file 100 bytes big.

At some point in my program execution, i end to have this:

```
char buffer[10];
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
ftell(fp) //100
int i = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp);
```

At the end of this snippet, `i=200`.

I get the same behaviour when i'm near the end of the file, like:

```
char buffer[10];
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
ftell(fp) //90
int i = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp);
printf("%d", i); // 190
```

How is this possible?

Comment: You are reading 100 elements of 0 bytes each. If you want to elements items of 1 byte each, and thus have fread() return the number of elements, which is also the number of bytes, use element size of 1.

Comment: Sorry, wrong code. Fixed with 1, thanks for notice.